# How to use join at a same type or index in ElasticSearch like solr

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Now I got a problem as I need to query some data from a type(or index) named 'product', and I have three parameters( $p1, $p2, $p3) which can determine some catagories,then I need get all the product in those catagories.
I know how it can be done in MySQL like this:

```
select * 
from product 
where catagory in (
    select catagory 
    from product
    where p1 = $p1 and p2=$p2 and p3=$p3
)
```

And I know I can do this in solr like

```
{!join from=catagory to=catagory}p1:$p1 AND p2:$p2 AND p3:$p3
```

But I want to know how can I do this in ElasticSearch.

BTW,sorry for my pool English. I do appreciate for your help.

Comment: besides, I also want you know that use the three parameters to query  can get over million catagories. So , I can not query catagories first and then pass those catagories as paratemeter to do another query

Answer (score 0):

after I look through official docs, this can be resolved like this:
1. create your index with a join type

```
put /product
     {
        "mappings":{
            "cata" : {
                "properties" : {
                     "join_field": { 
                          "type": "join",
                          "relations": {
                            "header": "line" 
                          }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

2. create a header data

   post /product

   ```
   {
       "p1":"1",
       "p2":"2",
       "p3":"3",
       "join_field":"header"
   }
   ```

   return with "_id:"xxx"
3. create a line data

post /cata?routing=xxx  (! routing must be header's '_id',so is 'parent' below)

```
{
    "p1":"1",
    "p2":"1",
    "p3":"1",
    "other":"others...",
    "join_field":{
        "name": "line",
        "parent": "xxx"
  }
}
```

4. query data
    post /cata/_search
`{
"query": {
    "has_parent" : {
        "parent_type" : "header",
        "query" : {
            "has_child" : {
                "type" : "line",
                "query" : {
                    "term" : {
                        "other" : "others..."
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}`

the way above fix my problem